# I get an error as [ Object reference not set ....] when i try to submit a form to store some values and the path of an uploaded image into database

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, ef-code-first

I have a form to store some records in events table in database along with the path of an uploaded file.

But when i click the Save button, it generates the following error:

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

This is my model:

```
public class events1
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string title { get; set; }
    public string report { get; set; }
    public string image1 { get; set; }
    public string image2 { get; set; }

    [NotMapped]
    public HttpPostedFileBase ImageFile { get; set; }
}
```

This is my controller

```
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var evt = _context.evt1;
        if (evt==null)
        {
            return Content("No events registered in database");
        }
        return View(evt);
    }



    public ActionResult Add_New()
    {

        return View();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Save(events1 e)
    {

        string filename = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(e.ImageFile.FileName);
        string extension = Path.GetExtension(e.ImageFile.FileName);
        filename = filename + DateTime.Now.ToString("yymmssfff") + extension;
        e.image1 = "~/Uploaded_Files/" + filename;
        filename = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/Uploaded_Files/"), filename);
        e.ImageFile.SaveAs(filename);



        _context.evt1.Add(e);
        _context.SaveChanges();
        ModelState.Clear();

        return RedirectToAction("Index","Events1");
    }
```

And this is the view:

```
   @model UploadFile_Button.Models.events1
@{
ViewBag.Title = "Add_New";
Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
 }

 @using (Html.BeginForm("Save", "Events1"))

 {
<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(a => a.title)
    @Html.TextBoxFor(a => a.title, new { @class = "form-control" })
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(a => a.report)
    @Html.TextBoxFor(a => a.report, new { @class = "form-control" })
</div>
<div class="form-group">
   <input type="file" name="ImageFile"/>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(a => a.image2)
    @Html.TextBoxFor(a => a.image2, new { @class = "form-control" })
</div>
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Save</button>
}
```

I have to mention when it generates the error, it also highlights this line of my code in RED color:

> ```
> string filename = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(e.ImageFile.FileName);
> ```

Comment: You need to add the `enctype='multipart/form-data` attribute to your form (without it, file inputs are not posted)

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because some line in your action method for Save is throwing an exception i.e. run time error. The error `Object reference not set to an instance of an object` means some object in your Save method is null and your code is trying to call a method on this null object. Most likely, its some object in the line that you have mentioned. (NOTE: Remember that a method can never be called on an object that is null.)

> string filename =
>   Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(e.ImageFile.FileName);

To prevent this error from occurring make sure that a valid parameter is being passed to your action method of Save and also check in the same same method if object e is null or object ImageFile is null before running remaining code in Save method as shown below.

```
if(e != null && e.ImageFile != null) {
  //your action code goes here
  string filename = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(e.ImageFile.FileName);
  //other code goes here

}
```